# How to approach digital electronics questions

Tags: digital-logic, interview-questions

I have an interview to a board design position, and I assume I'll be asked about digital electronics, so I'm reviewing some of the material by searching for questions online.

I'm seeing questions like:

- Give a circuit to divide frequency of clock cycle by two.
- Design a simple circuit based on combinational logic to double the
  output frequency.
- Implement D- latch using a multiplexer.

And so on.

While I have the knowledge, I'm still not sure how to approach these kind of questions where you have to design circuits. Is there some kind of method, technique to do so?

Forgive me if this is a broad/generic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Art of Electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics) (first edition anyway) noted that in designing, there are:

"...a few laws of physics, a few rules of thumb and a very large bag of tricks".

What you are asking falls into that bag of tricks that are easily findable, but require experience to understand.

All the questions you ask are easy to implement, *if you have the necessary experience*, which from your question, you do not appear to have.

We design by looking at the various requirements and looking at various ways to solve it; how we solve it is largely based on experience which a solid grounding in electronics yields.

I suspect each of us has their own approach.